# Retrieve stderr from a python program in a c++ one

Tags: python, c++, pipe, stderr, traceback

I'm currently trying to launch a file written in python from my C++ program with the pstream library (http://pstreams.sourceforge.net/). My code look like this:

```
QStringList res;
QStringList resErrors;

// run a process and create a streambuf that reads its stdout and stderr
redi::pstream proc(cmd, redi::pstreams::pstdout | redi::pstreams::pstderr);

std::string line;
// read child's stdout
while (std::getline(proc.out(), line))
    res.append(QString::fromStdString(line));
// read child's stderr
while (std::getline(proc.err(), line))
    resErrors.append(QString::fromStdString(line));
```

Usually I correctly receive out and err message from any command entered in the pstream constructor. But if I try to execute a python file that raise a traceback I don't have any output (in stdout or in stderr).

For example, this python file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

test = 5 / 0
print "test"
```

will no print "test" in stdout and nothing in stderr. But if I execute it in a terminal, I correctly got:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
       test = 5 / 0
   ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

In both case I used the same command: "python test.py"

I guess I need to tell to python to print its traceback to stderr? But why  it isn't done in a subprocess ? Or can it be a bug in the library?

Another possibility that I have in mind is that I read the stdout and stderr too early and python hadn't the time to write in it. But I have tried to add a sleep function before read it, without any effect.

Comment: reading stdout THEN stderr can lead to deadlocks. you have to read them in separate threads / find a non-blocking way to read them.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. But actually I have no deadlocks as the two "while condition" are invalidated. It's just like there is no output at all in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem is effectively solved with a part of the answer from @Jean-François Fabre.

I noticed that pstreams provide a way to read on pipe without blocking, so I reuse that code (found in the doc of the library):

```
const redi::pstreams::pmode mode = redi::pstreams::pstdout|redi::pstreams::pstderr;
redi::ipstream child(cmd, mode);
char buf[1024];
std::streamsize n;
bool finished[2] = { false, false };
while (!finished[0] || !finished[1])
{
    if (!finished[0])
    {
        while ((n = child.err().readsome(buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0) {
            std::string ret(buf, n);
            resErrors.append(QString::fromStdString(ret));
        }
        if (child.eof())
        {
            finished[0] = true;
            if (!finished[1])
                child.clear();
        }
    }

    if (!finished[1])
    {
        while ((n = child.out().readsome(buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0) {
            std::string out(buf, n);
            res.append(QString::fromStdString(out));
        }
        if (child.eof())
        {
            finished[1] = true;
            if (!finished[0])
                child.clear();
        }
    }
}
res = res.join("").split("\n");
resErrors = resErrors.join("").split("\n");
res.removeLast();
resErrors.removeLast();
```

With this, I have all outputs in my QStringLists!